# Is there a CRAN friendly way to have variables defined as a side-effect in R?

Tags: r, cran, side-effects

Is there a way to use a function-call to set up a collection of variables with new names?

What I'd like is something like the following:

```
helper <- function (x) {
  y <<- x + 1
  NULL
}

main <- function (x) {
  helper(x)
  return(y)  
}
```

However, there are two problems with this:

- the code means that `y` is defined in the global environment, which I don't want;
- I'm also aware that the `<<-` operator is not kosher as far as CRAN is concerned.

Essentially I'd like to make my function `main` cleaner by passing a lot of the work it does to `helper`.  Is there any legitimate way to do this for a package that I eventually want to be on CRAN?

Comment: You might also want to check out the OO options in R. See e.g. http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html

Answer (score 3):

I don't think your approach is in any way really sensible (why not use a List), but if you really want to do that, you can use `assign` to assign variables in arbitrary environments, e.g. the parent frame:

```
helper <- function(x) {
  assign('y', x + 1, envir=parent.frame())
  NULL
}

main <- function(x) {
  helper(x)
  return(y)  
}

main(1)
# [1] 2
```

Comment: How can I do this with a list, other than by having the function return a long list and then assign each entry in the list to the variable I want it assigned to?

Comment: I would probably just use the list elements themselves. If you really want to do have the elements as variables inside the function, you could use `assign` in a `lapply` call on the list elements to assign them in the local environment

Answer (score 0):

You can use the strategy to have `helper` returning a list with the calculated variables and then use them:

```
helper <- function (x) {
  y <- x + 1
  list(y = y)
}

main <- function (x) {
  vars <- helper(x)
  return(vars$y)  
}
```

If you are going to use `y` often and don't want to always type `var$s`, you could assign it locally:

```
main <- function (x) {
  vars <- helper(x)
  y <- vars$y
  return(y)  
}
```

In contrast to assigning variables in arbitrary environments, this makes it way easier to reason what your code does.

Comment: I don't really want to just return `y`, that was just a MWE. I really want to get a lot of variables and then do other things with them!